# Python Pynput Issue

Tags: python

Hello I am having trouble with this code

I am trying to create a pynput app that autoinputs text when I press a certain combination of keys but this does not work as intended instead of receiving `HELlO` it only types the uppercase characters from my variable and the result is this `HELO` this also happens for spaces I won t type those

````py
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

k = Controller()

def on_activate_h():
     word = "HELlO"
     k.type(word)
    


with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
        '<ctrl>+<alt>+h': on_activate_h,
        }) as h:
    h.join()```
````

Comment: where have you tried typing into

Comment: Visual studio code node pad discord etc
I asked this questions on discord forums aswell but the people that answered me told me it works fine for them I don t get why it does not work the way it s intended to lol

Comment: Well i can't help you then. Is that the exact code you are working with? Is your caps lock on maybe? might that be an issue?

Comment: Yes it is the exact code and no my capslock is not on I thought about that but it s not the issue